# How to turn servo to a specific location and then turn over

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, servo

I work on my first arduino car project and i want to turn my servo to a position with a letter input

This is my code so far

```
 #include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;

 void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
 }

 void loop() {

 if(Serial.available()>0){
 int  caz=Serial.read();
 switch(caz)
{
  case 'w':
      digitalWrite(8,LOW);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      break;
  case 's':
      digitalWrite(7,LOW);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      break;
  case'd':
       servo.attach(12);
       servo.write(0);
       break;
  case'a':
       servo.attach(11);
       servo.write(180);
       break;
   default:
       digitalWrite(7,LOW);
       digitalWrite(8,LOW);
       servo.attach(0);
  }
}
```

when i input 'a' or 'd' it starts turning until i input something else and i want it to stop after 10-30 degree .

And also i would like to do that to my motor , moving a bit when i input the key.

Comment: Nice use of a switch statement :D

Comment: I found out that my servo 360 Parallax has continuous rotation

Comment: You should get a 180 degree servo. You code looks fine and it should work with a 180 degree servo. Read my comment under the answer by Matt. Using .write command on continuous servos tells them the speed and direction in which to rotate, not the angle.

Comment: @user6317433 are you still in need of an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing to 180 and 0 write to a variable.

```
static const int MovementAmount = 30; //degrees
int position = 90;  // 90 is the start position.
...
case 'd':
   servo.attach(12);
   position += MovementAmount;
   if (position > 180)
   {
     position = 180;
   }
   servo.write(position);
   break;
```

Comment: Doesn't the servo.write need to be outside of the if statement?

Comment: 'MovementAmount' it should be the position ,number?

Comment: @Matt does it matter what kind of servo i have ?

Comment: @Gerben - Doh :)  That would help wouldn't it, I'll edit it.

Comment: @user6317433 - The movement amount is the amount you want it to move by every time you press the relative key.  You will need a block of code like this for case 'a'.
  I don't think a continuous servo will affect the code, but you will have to remember to use -MovementAmount and +MovementAmount. otherwise it will turn around where you don't want it to go.

Comment: @Matt I actually believe that it won't work with continuous servos. When saying servo.write(180), that means rotate full speed one way. write(0) is full speed the opposite way. 90 is stop. I do not think that there is a way to get precise angles with continuous servos.